# xCode Build Script using info.plist with space in the name

Tags: xcode, bash, build-process

I am trying to automatically increment the build number with the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Auto Increment Version Script
buildPlist="Project-Info.plist"
buildVersion=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBuildVersion" $buildPlist)
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBuildNumber" $buildPlist)
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBuildNumber $buildNumber" $buildPlist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildVersion.$buildNumber" $buildPlist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleShortVersionString $buildVersion.$buildNumber" $buildPlist
```

However, my buildPlist file name has a space ie. "Foo App.plist" This will cause the script to fail. Any quick fixes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Problem solved.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Auto Increment Version Script
echo "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
buildVersion=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleShortVersionString" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
buildNumber=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print CFBundleVersion" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}")
buildNumber=$(($buildNumber + 1))
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleVersion $buildNumber" "${PROJECT_DIR}/${INFOPLIST_FILE}"
```